# How to erase elements from boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

So I'm trying to get rid of my std::vector's by using boost::ptr_vector. Now I'm trying to remove an element from one, and have the removed element deleted as well. The most obvious thing to me was to do:

```
class A
{ int m; };

boost::ptr_vector<A> vec;
A* a = new A;
vec.push_back(a);
vec.erase(a);
```

But this won't even compile (see below for the full error message). I've tried the erase/remove idiom like I would on a std::vector but all the algorithms of boost::ptr_vector turn out to be slightly different from those in std::vector.

So my questions:

- How do I remove a pointer from a ptr_vector?
- Do I still need to manually delete() that element that I removed?

Compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ptr_vector_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>ptr_vector_test.cpp
1>c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp(37) : error C2825: 'C': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>        c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(63) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_const_iterator<C>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=A *
1>        ]
1>        c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\iterator.hpp(63) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<C,F1,F2>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=true,
1>            F1=boost::range_const_iterator<A *>,
1>            F2=boost::range_mutable_iterator<A *const >
1>        ]
1>        c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\ptr_container\detail\reversible_ptr_container.hpp(506) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_iterator<C>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=A *const 
1>        ]
1>        c:\tmp\ptr_vector_test\ptr_vector_test.cpp(21) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::void_ptr_iterator<VoidIter,T> boost::ptr_container_detail::reversible_ptr_container<Config,CloneAllocator>::erase<A*>(const Range &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            VoidIter=std::_Vector_iterator<void *,std::allocator<void *>>,
1>            T=A,
1>            Config=boost::ptr_container_detail::sequence_config<A,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *>>>,
1>            CloneAllocator=boost::heap_clone_allocator,
1>            Range=A *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp(37) : error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp(37) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
1>c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp(37) : error C2208: 'boost::type' : no members defined using this type
1>c:\users\rvanhout\svn\trunk\thirdparty\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp(37) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\tmp\ptr_vector_test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ptr_vector_test - 5 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you can do that with a std::vector either.

In both cases erase takes an iterator as a parameter.
So before you can erase something from a vector (or a ptr_vector) you need to locate it.

Also note that the ptr_vector treats its content as if you have stored an object not a pointer. So any searching is done via the object.

So basically

```
 std::vector<A>       x;
 std::ptr_vector<A>   y;

 // These two object should behave in exactly the same way.
 // The ONLY difference is inserting values which for y are pointers.
 // Y take ownership of the pointer and all subsequent acesses to the
 // members of y look like they are objects
```

Example:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <vector>

class A
{ int m;
    public:
    A(int x):m(x)   {}
    bool operator==(A const& rhs)   {return m = rhs.m;}
};

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<A>    x;
    x.push_back(new A(1));
    x.erase(std::find(x.begin(),x.end(),A(1)));


    std::vector<A>          y;
    y.push_back(A(2));
    y.erase(std::find(y.begin(),y.end(),A(2)));

    // To find an exact pointer don't modify the equality.
    // Use find_if and pass a predicate that tests for a pointer
    A* a = new A(3);
    boost:ptr_Vector<A>     z;
    z.push_back(a);
    z.erase(std::find_if(y.begin(),y.end(),CheckPointerValue(a));
}

struct CheckPointerValue
{
     CheckPointerValue(A* a):anA(a) {}
     bool operator()(A const& x)    { return &X == anA;}
     private:
        A* anA;
};
```

Comment: i think you were right about my answer below. if i understand it right, the default allocator (heap_clone_allocator) clones the objects itself when reallocating). it would have worked if using the view_clone_allocator though. i've removed my answer and upvoted you. have fun :)

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that I hadn't defined the == operator for A* const & which seems to be necessary. To get your example to compile (VC9), I had to change "A const& rhs" to "A* const& rhs" and change the content of the body accordingly. That makes it hard to use with library classes though.

Comment: You are missing the point! The ptr_vector<> stores the object like they are an object. Rather than perverting the equality operator just de-reference the pointer. If you want to find an exact pointer you need to use find_if and pass a predicate.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to call .release() on the vector instead of erase. That removes the entry and deletes the memory.

See the section "New Functions" for details in [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html), or check [the reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html).

Alternatively, you need to get an iterator to an element in order to call erase(), I'm ot sure an A* counts in terms of a ptr_vector.

Comment: No - `release` removes the pointer from the container, and the container shrinks, but the object isn't deleted. It has the same semantics as `auto_ptr` `release` - you just use it to transfer management.

Answer (score 1):

You can use erase_if template method.

```
vec.erase_if( predicate() );
```

Comment: But then I'd need to write a special-purpose predicate which basically is a simple comparison function object? What a mess, if that's the way I'm supposed to work with ptr_vector I'll just stick with my vector of shared_ptr's :/

Comment: Use boost::lambda to write the predicate as a lambda function (in place).

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `ptr_vector` are very similar to a regular `vector`. You have to find an element before you can erase it.

Comment: Yep, erase takes an iterator, ptr_vector is no different.

Comment: How do I find things in a ptr_vector? boost::ptr_vector<A>::iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a); doesn't work. (error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)).

Comment: I guess I need a ptr_iterator, but that one seems to be protected (although I could find postings to mailings lists where it was used, so I guess it was made protected later on...).

Answer (score 1):

Curious thing:  [STL::vector<>](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) is a [Random Access Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessContainer.html), meaning that it uses [Random Access Iterators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html).

So **vec.erase(vec.begin()+N)** will remove the element at index N.

Note that doing so breaks the whole *iterator* meme and you can no longer trivially switch between vectors and lists...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the member erase_if method with a suitable predicate. There's no need to delete the pointer, the container has ownership.

```
struct delete_a {
    bool operator()(boost::ptr_vector<A>::value_type inA) {
       return inA == a;
    }
}

vec.erase_if(delete_a());
```

(note this is just an example chosen for simplicity, for such situation in real code I suppose one would write a suitable bind/equal_to combo, or use lambda)

Or, as an alternative, call release on the correct iterator, if you still want to use the object.