# How to erase "this" from boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I have a boost::ptr_vector containing pointers to class "holdable".

```
boost::ptr_vector<holdable> items;
```

I add new items to this vector from within the holdable class like this:

```
currentplanet->items.push_back(this);
```

where currentplanet is a pointer to an object of the class containing the ptr_vector.  This is all fine.

What I'm confused about is how to remove an entry from the ptr_vector from a function within its own class.  I'm trying:

```
currentplanet->items.erase(std::find(currentplanet->items.begin(),
                                     currentplanet->items.end(),
                                     this));
```

as in accordance with the answer to a similar question here: [How to erase elements from boost::ptr_vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356002/how-to-erase-elements-from-boostptr-vector), but i've obviously gone wrong somewhere, probably with regard to the use of "this".

On trying to compile, i receive an error from stl_algo.h saying

```
stl_algo.h|174|error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.boost::void_ptr_iterator<VoidIter, T>::operator*
  [with VoidIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<void**, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> > >, 
  T = holdable]() == __val'|
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but i'm probably getting confused by ptr_vector's indirection... thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Your design is flawed in any case, I think. A `ptr_vector` *owns* the pointers in it. If you already have a `this`, something *else* owns that object. It doesn't make sense to add it to the `ptr_vector`. Just use a `std::vector<holdable*>` for a non-owning reference to all the things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other wrote - it is true that `ptr_vector` takes ownership of your object, but if you insist to be able for object to be removed from `ptr_vector` by itself - use find_if, not find:

```
Holdable* ptr = this;
currentplanet->items.erase(std::find_if(currentplanet->items.begin(),
                                        currentplanet->items.end(),
                                        [ptr](const Holdable& other) 
                                        {return ptr == &other;} ));
```

Note that `find` used with `*this` might find other object which is equal to `*this`...

---

For compilers still not supporting lambda expression (this thing starting from `[ptr]`), use your own predicate:

```
struct CompareToPtr { 
    CompareToPtr(Holdable* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    bool operator () (const Holdable& other) const { return &other == ptr; }
    Holdable* ptr;
};
currentplanet->items.erase(std::find_if(currentplanet->items.begin(),
                                        currentplanet->items.end(),
                                        CompareToPtr(this)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm afraid this throws a
    holdable.h|48|error: expected primary-expression before '[' token|

(where line 48 starts with [ptr] in the above snippet).  Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: @Riot: PiotrNycz's code snippet uses a C++11 lambda expression which your compiler might not support (or might need an option specified to enable such support).  If C++11 isn't an option for you, you can make the `find_if()` predicate argument (what the lambda is being used for) a functor or even a plain old function instead.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that std::find requires a value (not a pointer) for the third param, so you pass a ["begin", "end") range in which to seek, and the value you seek

Is this what you meant ?

```
currentplanet->items.erase(std::find(currentplanet->items.begin(),
                                     currentplanet->items.end(),
                                     *this));
```

note the *this

Comment: Other objects in ptr_vector might be equal to `*this` - so not necessarily `this` object iterator will be returned.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the first thing i tried - that doesn't seem to be valid code.  The compiler says:
    stl_algo.h|174|error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.boost::void_ptr_iterator<VoidIter, T>::operator* [with VoidIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<void**, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> > >, T = holdable]() == __val'|

Answer (score 2):

[Alf is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329421/12711), but for a reason that's somewhat peculiar to `boost::ptr_vector` (and the other related `boost::reversible_ptr_container` containers) that I think shoould be called out.  Usually an iterator to a container's element will dereference to a reference to the the container's `value_type`.

`boost:ptr_vector<T>::value_type` is a typedef for `T*`; however dereferencing a `boost::ptr_vector<T>::iterator` doesn't result in a `T*` reference.

From the Boost docs (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reversible_ptr_container.html):

> Also notice that
>
> ```
> typedef ... iterator
> ```
>
> allows one to iterate over T& objects, not T*.

Dereferencing a `boost::ptr_vector<T>::iterator` results in a `T&`. That's why you were getting confused by ptr_vector's indirection, and that's why the last argument to `std::find()` needs to be a `holdable` object rather than a `holdable*`.

Finally, note that Xeo's comment about `ptr_vector` taking ownership of the pointers to should be understood - it might make sense in very limited situations for an object to want to delete itself, but you should do so with the full understanding that after that `erase()` call, you can't do anything more with the object.  If that's not the behavior you need, instead of `erase()` you might want to consider using `release()`, which will release the container's ownership of the pointer along with removing it from the container (so the object will not be destroyed).

Comment: Thank you, but as i commented on Alf's reply, using "*this" produces a compiler error.  Is there some way round this i should be aware of?

Incidentally, to clarify - this is indeed in a situation where the object is to delete itself.

Comment: I think at this point the problem is that you have no `operator==()` that allows `holdable` objects to be compared.  You might want to post a small but complete example that compilers to show the error you're seeing (the example probably needs a `class holdable` but you can probably get away without needing a `currentplanet` object).

Comment: However, you should take note of PiotrNycz's answer - you definitely need to deal with the problem of `holdable` objects that compare the same - either by using his solution of `find_if()` using object addresses or by not permitting such a condition to happen among the objects in `items` (which might be a rather fragile way to handle the problem).